# In Gmail can we make 'is:unread' the default view?

Tags: gmail

In Gmail can we make `is:unread` the default view?

That is, when we load Gmail, can we configure it so that `is:unread` is already selected, thereby showing only unread messages by default?

[image: screen shot of Gmail search results]

Or can we at least configure Gmail so that it has a 1-click link that only shows unread mail?

The reason for this of course is that it is slow and inefficient to have to type `is:unread` into the Gmail search every time I open it.  It would be much more convenient for Gmail to load this view by itself when I open Gmail.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Have you considered just setting your Priority Inbox settings so that Unread is always displayed first?

[image: unread first]

Comment: "priority" is no longer in the settings page............

Answer (score 4):

Add a bookmark to this link: https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/#search/is%3Aunread

Then it is accessible via a single click. Or assign it a keyboard shortcut if you like.

Comment: This ties the setting to the individual browser instead of to the account.